# A reusable way to display error / result messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, message

I'm developping an mvc-app and I want to render "error messages" to the screen when an action is invalid.

Here's an example of what I do.

Suppose the following case:

```
int result = _quantityToUse - item.quantityLeft;
```

This error message could consist, in this case, of the fact that the `result` value cannot be negative. Here's what I do in this case:

```
if(result < 0)
{
   ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "There are not enough left of this item to use.";

   return View();
}
```

and, in my view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Object Management";
}

<h2>
    Object Management
</h2>

<span id="emptyMessage">@ViewData["ErrorMessage"]</span>
```

Using Css, I display an error message that I nullify when I'm back in the controller action, and refill if there's an invalid condition. Something quite basic, but efficient.

Now, my problem is that I have to manage each view using this filter. I would like instead to process something, maybe a partial view, I don't know how, but something that would be reusable and that, if I needed to modify, would only need to be modified once, not at every occurrence. Since almost all of my views make use of error / result message, that would be very useful.

Anybody has a good idea how I might do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse, you can have an 'Error.cshtml' partial view that'll render errors if your ViewBag has any. And you could hook this up on your master view (_Layout.cshtml).

Have a section in your master view, something like:

```
                <section id="errors">
                    @Html.Partial("_Error")
                </section>
```

Now, you could have an Error.cshtml which would be something like:

```
@ if (ViewData["ErrorMessage"] != null) {
    <span id="emptyMessage">@ViewData["ErrorMessage"]</span>
}
```

Comment: Interesting! How might I do that?

Comment: Might be an interesting way to do this :) Thank you

Comment: No mention - and by the way, don't forget to mark this as the answer if you don't come across a better solution :-)